# React Action Creator and Action Type Naming Convention?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Are there any official naming convention on naming action creators and action.types

Looking over tutorials the theme of the action creator and action type is to name the action type pretty much one to one with action creator.

To use an example lets say we have an application fetching blog posts

The tutorial (top rated Udemy tutorial) used the following naming convention with asynchronous action creator:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await postsAPI.get('/posts');

    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data});
};
```

However, wouldnt it make more sense to name the action objects more precisely (to signify success or failure) to what is being dispatched. Rather than matching action creator function name with action type, along the lines of:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await postsAPI.get('/posts');
    
    if (response.status === 200) {
       dispatch({type: 'FETCHED_POSTS', payload: response.data});
    } else {
        dispatch({type: 'FAILED_TO_FETCH_POSTS', payload: response});
    }
};
```

Comment: This article here willl help you. https://decembersoft.com/posts/a-simple-naming-convention-for-action-creators-in-redux-js/. For async actions I generally like to use ```FETCH_POST_REQUEST``` ```FETCH_POST_SUCCESS``` ```FETCH_POST_FAILURE```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the official style guides suggests to [write action types as `domain/eventname`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#write-action-types-as-domaineventname).

This goes along with a few other things from the style guide.

- the [recommendation to use redux toolkit](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-redux-toolkit-for-writing-redux-logic) instead of writing redux logic by hand, which allows you to create slices, which will automatically prefix all action names for a slice. (Also, you'll no longer need to write action types, action creators, switch-case statements or immutable logic by hand as RTK does that for you, see [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux))
- the [recommendation to organize your files by feature](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#structure-files-as-feature-folders-or-ducks)
- the recommendation to [model actions as events](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters)
- the recommendation to [write meaningful action names](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#write-meaningful-action-names)

Adding to that, I prefer my actions to be in the past like `todos/added` when they describe something that happened in the application or something the user did, and to be in the imperative like `todos/save` when they describe a side effect that should be handled in a middleware (which will then maybe do an API request and end up in a `todos/saved` action to actually lead to changes in a reducer).

A few more things are implicitly done by RTK, for example [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) will autmatically create three actions for every thunk:
`yourActionPrefix/pending`, `yourActionPrefix/fulfilled` and `yourActionPrefix/rejected`.

Comment: I think that `save`/`saved` is a clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you in that communicating the specific type of object being dispatched improves clarity, but I also think it's important to show how actions are related to each other. This can be achieved by using some prefix for related actions, along with suffixes to denote different cases.

e.g. So with the prefix `FETCH_POSTS`, you can have action names like

- `FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST`
- `FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS`
- `FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE`

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await postsAPI.get('/posts');
    
    if (response.status === 200) {
       dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', payload: response.data});
    } else {
        dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', payload: response});
    }
};
```

One further step you could take is to use a constants object that defines these actions names. This is because action names are reused in several places (action creators, reducers, unit tests, etc), and having action names defined as constants enforces consistency and readability.

```
export const POSTS_API_ACTIONS = {
   FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST: 'FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST',
   FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS',
   FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE',
   DELETE_POSTS_REQUEST: 'DELETE_POSTS_REQUEST',
   ...
}

export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await postsAPI.get('/posts');

    if (response.status === 200) {
       dispatch({type: POSTS_API_ACTIONS.FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data});
    } else {
        dispatch({type: POSTS_API_ACTIONS.FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE, payload: response});
    }
};
```